# Add a new field on my model and on my user interface

Tags: python, django, angular

I'm new to Django and Angular, I've just started my internship and I'm working on an application that uses Angular for the frontend and Django for the backend.

I've added a new field to one of my models, I did the migration, but I don't know what the next step is going to be?  Do I need to add something in the views?

My goal is to also add this field on the user interface so that the user can select the correct information.

Comment: Update your question and show some part on which you are working. 
Check how you are currently rendering the page, You are possibly passing the data through views and using Django rest framework. So, you have to check what data you are currently getting through that API and update it as per requirement. Also, you will need to add that field in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Did you develop a rest API using Django for your Angular project? If so, you need to add (GET/POST) Add method on your rest side and return the object with the field from the database.

As soon as you get the object you can do whatever you want on the frontend side, for example, view the field value to the user.

Comment: Actually, the API is already developed I am just completing the project. we are using an MVC architecture. Thank you for your response